# Why is scipy's probability density function not accepting size of my mean?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I am using a function to calculate a likelihood density.

I am running through two xs which are vectors of length 7.

```
def lhd(x0, x1, dt): #Define a function to calculate the likelihood density given two values. 
    d = len(x0) #Save the length of the inputs for the below pdf input.
    print(d)
    print(len(x1))
    lh = multivariate_normal.pdf(x1, mean=(1-dt)*x0, cov=2*dt*np.identity(d)) #Take the pdf from a multivariate normal built from x0, given x1.
    return lh #Return this pdf value.
```

The mean here is a vector of length 7, and the covariance is a (7,7) array.

When I run this, I get the error

```
ValueError: Array 'mean' must be a vector of length 49.
```

but looking at the formula of the pdf I do not think this is correct. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If `dt` is a (7,7) array, `(1-dt)` is also (7,7), the `*` operator in `(1-dt)*x0` is the element-wise multiplication, if `x0` is a vector of length 7 the result will be a (7,7) array.

I guess you meant to use matrix multiplication, you can that this using the `x0 - dt @ x0` (where `@` denotes the matrix multiplication operator).